# Testing equality for visually identical characters with different UTF-8 encodings. (Japanese)

Tags: python, string, encoding, utf-8, difflib

In my project I need to deal with many different languages, one of them is Japanese. (I don't speak it myself).

I need to compare two strings to see if they are equal. One string comes from a filename on my computer, the other string is from the download link of that exact file. These 2 strings should be the same.

Turns out the same characters can be encoded in different ways or something like that.

Look at the character **バ**, it can be encoded in two ways.

1. `\xe3\x83\x90`
2. `\xe3\x83\x8f\xe3\x82\x99`

Number 2 is actually an **ハ** and a **゙** together, which results in same character. Because of this some strings will be considered different, even if they should be equal. Python is telling me that

> ネバーランド

is not the same as

> ネバーランド

Things I have tried:

- Instead of checking for exact equality I tried using similarity:

  `difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, string1, string2).ratio()` This unfortunately is not precise enough. I've also tried configuring junk but I cant get it to be precise enough.
- Messing around with the decode and encode functions hoping that it would just magically disappear.

I've seen somewhat similar questions asked but no good solutions and i'm afraid there is none unless I filter out these special cases manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalize into its combined form. But operate with `unicode`s, of course, not UTF-8.

```
>>> u'ネバーランド' == u'ネバーランド'
False
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFC', u'ネバーランド') == u'ネバーランド'
True
```